# Using PHP to get xml selector attributes

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to access the xml attributes using php. I can access the actual text of any field, but

For example, a line from the xml file looks like this:

```
<Competitor CODE1="MIN" CODE3="MIN" CODE4="l.mlb.com-t.10" ID="69" LineOrderOverride="" NAME="Minnesota Twins" NUM="1" ROT="927" SCORE="5">Game 1</Competitor>
```

The code I am using will show me "Game 1" but I want to be able to access the NAME and SCORE values

```
@$doc->load($feedURL);
$arrFeeds = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('Event') as $node) {
$itemRSS = array ( 
echo strip_tags(str_replace("'","",$node->getElementsByTagName('Competitor')->item(0)->nodeValue));
};
```

Does anyone know a way to access the meta variables using PHP?

Comment: You forgot to post an example of XML input file...

Comment: you should use dom xpath

Answer (score 0):

Inside your foreach(), add

```
echo $node->getElementsByTagName('Competitor')->item(0)->getAttribute("NAME"); // For NAME
echo $node->getElementsByTagName('Competitor')->item(0)->getAttribute("SCORE"); // For SCORE
```